# batch not capturing hidden files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

The following lines allowed me to list all the files, folders, and sub-folders in file TXT, but the problem is that the hidden files are not included in file TXT. So, what do I have to do?

```
@echo off
set /a VAR=%random%  
mkdir C:\Users\Blm\Desktop\folder\
for /r  E:\ %%i in (*) do (echo %%i >> C:\Users\Blm\Desktop\folder\%VAR%.txt)
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
for /r  E:\ %%i in (*) do (echo %%i >> C:\Users\Blm\Desktop\folder\%VAR%.txt)
```

With this one:

```
dir /s/o/b /a E:\ > C:\Users\Blm\Desktop\folder\%VAR%.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /s /ah /b
```

- `/s` include **s**ub-folders
- `/ah` include **h**idden files (attribute, hidden)
- `/b` in **b**are format (file list only, no columns for size or type)

you don't need to use `for` loop for simply listing a directory tree

You may use `attrib /s /d` instead of `dir` for a similar function but different output displaying file and folder attributes (that's if they're hidden, system, archieve type of files etc) too

Also you might consider using `tree /f` instead, for a better output formatting, although without showing the hidden files